# findBy doesn't join ManyToMany relations

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have two entities: Card and Tag. Card has a property tags that is a relation ManyToMany to Tag

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=App\Repository\V2\LM\CardRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="lm_cards")
 */
class Card {
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
   * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
   */
  private $id;

  // Foreign keys
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Branch::class)
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
   */
  private $branch;

  [...]

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="cards")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="operator_id")
   */
  private $operator;

  [...]

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Tag::class)
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="lm_cards_tags")
   */
  private $tags;

  [...]
```

Tag class doesn't have any property pointing to Card.

Now I want to get a collection of Card instances based on some criteria; the $criteria array contains an element with key 'tags' and value an array of Tag instances:

`$cardRepository->findBy($criteria);`

This call returns an Unknown column error in SQL, so, reading the generated query I see that in where clause doctrine resolves correctly the relation (lm_cards_tags.tag_id IN (?)) but it doesn't JOIN the table in the FROM clause

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.form_note AS form_note_2, t0.priority AS priority_3, t0.provenance_uri AS provenance_uri_4, t0.title AS title_5, t0.branch_id AS branch_id_6, t0.category_id AS category_id_7, t0.step_id AS step_id_8, t0.real_estate_id AS real_estate_id_9, t0.operator_id AS operator_id_10 FROM lm_cards t0 WHERE t0.branch_id = ? AND lm_cards_tags.tag_id IN (?) AND t0.step_id = ?' with params [2, "10c43b57-f0df-4075-a6f2-2d10550a2e69", "4780cf87-b427-11ed-9b76-0242c0a80203"]:Unknown column 'lm_cards_tags.tag_id' in 'where clause'
```

Reading the documentation, Doctrine must manage all the relationships in background, so why it doesn't here? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How is tag supposed to know which field it will use as id for the ManyToMany? You should at least add a [InverseJoinColumn](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.15/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional) to doctrine definition if you don't want to define the relation in both classes

Comment: Considering that the envolved entities are two, that the pivot table is well formed with the relative two fields (card_id and tag_id) and that I'll never search for tag->cards but only for card->tags, I supposed that doctrine doesn't need to know the inversse relation. By the way I'll try your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: If you did not deviate from the defaults asked by doctrine, I agree. Have you try the "validate-schema" command? No errors there?

Comment: doctrine:chema:validate response is `[OK] The mapping files are correct.`
I've modified the annotation declaration in Card as you suggested:

/**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Tag::class)
   * @ORM\JoinTable(
   *   name="lm_cards_tags",
   *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="card_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\joinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
   * )
   */
  private $tags;

Nothing changed, same error and JOIN missing.

Comment: Ok so the doctrine config is good. I tend to avoid M2M relationships but It seems the findBy doesn't do well with the field in the related table. I guess using the getter for simple case or using a querybuilder is the way to go